# Sending emails with Django and Post Office

Tags: python, django

I have some trouble setting up an email option for my django project.
I am using post office for the backend, but I can't seem to get anything to queue.

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from post_office import mail

class EmailView(TemplateView):

    model = Customer
    mail.send(
        'a.sophiewirth@gmail.com', # List of email addresses also accepted
        'your.generic.test.email@gmail.com',
        subject='My email',
        message='Hi there!',
        html_message='Hi <strong>there</strong>!',
    )
    template_name = 'customers/send_email.html'
```

settings.py:

```
# using post office as the default email backend
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'post_office.EmailBackend'

POST_OFFICE = {
    'DEFAULT_PRIORITY' : 'now'
}

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "your.generic.test.email@gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 25  # default smtp port
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "password"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'your.generic.test.email@gmail.com'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from customers.views import CustomerList, CreateCustomerView, CustomerUpdateView, EmailView
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', CustomerList.as_view(), name="customer-list"),
    url(r'^create-customer$', CreateCustomerView.as_view(), name="create-customer"),
    url(r'^customer-update/(?P<pk>\d+)$', CustomerUpdateView.as_view(), name="customer-update"),
    url(r'^send-email$', EmailView.as_view(), name="send-email"),
)
```

send_email.html itself is pretty empty thus far, it just contains a paragraph to tell you that you sent an email.

Can anyone tell me why nothing is sending? Also, how can I get the recipient of the email into the View, as the specific user I want to send the mail to?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: What queuing system are you using?

Comment: I am not using any other systems than django and postgres, currently. I didn't realise I needed to add a queuing system specifically. I did install celery on my machine. I am sorry, I am really new to the whole backend thing, so I am aware I come across as a huge noob.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being new to something. Give me a few minutes to finish something else and I'll post my Celery setup as an example. Someone else may have answered by then but at least now you know you're guaranteed at least one answer!

Comment: Thank you for being so kind and for helping me! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have both [djcelery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery) and [Django celery email](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery-email) installed. This is in an older project and I believe djcelery is no longer needed but my setup should still give you a start. My Django settings include the following:

```
import djcelery
...
djcelery.setup_loader()

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'post_office.EmailBackend'
POST_OFFICE_BACKEND = 'djcelery_email.backends.CeleryEmailBackend'
```

My project also includes a shell script, which I run to start and configure the celery daemon. My project is running in a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) so some of this may not be needed for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# user/group to run as
USER=your_username
GROUP=your_groupname
cd /path/to/virtualenv/
source ./bin/activate
cd /path/to/directory/containing/manage.py/
exec python manage.py celeryd --settings=directory.path.settings.py
```

Running the shell script should show you a running celery process and your emails should now send and queue happily.

Comment: Hey, so I modified my settings page. It now has:

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

# using djcelery's email backend as a backend for post office 
POST_OFFICE_BACKEND = 'djcelery_email.backends.CeleryEmailBackend'

But now my localhost just loads for ever when I try to send a mail. I also run rabbitmq, maybe that's a problem?

Comment: Oh wait, something I didn't see before is that I actually get an error from celery:

[2015-03-17 13:15:42,270: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 61] Connection refused.
Trying again in 18.00 seconds...

Comment: Okay, so I fired up rabbitmq again and the error message disappears, but still no mails :/

Answer (score 0):

remove default priority now and add `'CELERY_ENABLED': True`, to `POST_OFFICE` settings like this:

```py
 POST_OFFICE = {
     'CELERY_ENABLED': True,
 }
```

after this when u start celery worker you should see 2 tasks received from

```
post_office
post_office.tasks.cleanup_expired_mails
post_office.tasks.send_queued_mail
```